# How to get the output of commands from build scripts?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a `gcc` command which fails while building rust-crypto as a dependency of another package.

How do I get the output of that `gcc` command in order to know why that `gcc` call fails?

It seems that `--verbose` isn't the answer. While `-vv` shows the output of commands, it doesn't show the output of all of them. In my case the build script is one command where its sub-commands aren't shown.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: @Shepmaster you just removed from the question that it was happening while building the `rust-crypto` crate.

Comment: That's... [literally the first sentence of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkUnf.png).